# std::thread problems

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, valgrind, std

I think I have a kind really bad concepts problems. Why I simple get a lot of race conditions error with valgrind.
First i thought that could be a bug, and I saw in forums that an updated rolling release of linux will solve this... so now i have opensuse tubleweed, 100% updated.
The following code muss have something very wrong:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

class FOO
{
public:
    void do_something ()
    {
        cout<<"cout somethin\n";
    }
};

int main ()
{
    FOO foo;
    std::thread t (&FOO::do_something,&foo);
    t.join();
}
```

When i do a

```
valgrind --tool=drd ./oncordia
```

i have to try 5 times or more and i get the following errors:

```
==6218== drd, a thread error detector
==6218== Copyright (C) 2006-2010, and GNU GPL'd, by Bart Van Assche.
==6218== Using Valgrind-3.6.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==6218== Command: ./oncordia
==6218== 
cout somethin
==6218== Conflicting store by thread 1 at 0x05b5d050 size 8
==6218==    at 0x418E62: std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_result<void, std::_Mem_fn<void (FOO::*)()> ()(FOO*)> >::~_Impl() (in /home/ezequiel/projects/oncordia/build/oncordia)
==6218==    by 0x419099: std::_Sp_destroy_inplace<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_result<void, std::_Mem_fn<void (FOO::*)()> ()(FOO*)> > >::operator()(std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_result<void, std::_Mem_fn<void (FOO::*)()> ()(FOO*)> >*) const (in /home/ezequiel/projects/oncordia/build/oncordia)
==6218==    by 0x418EDC: std::_Sp_counted_deleter<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_result<void, std::_Mem_fn<void (FOO::*)()> ()(FOO*)> >*, std::_Sp_destroy_inplace<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_result<void, std::_Mem_fn<void (FOO::*)()> ()(FOO*)> > >, std::allocator<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_result<void, std::_Mem_fn<void (FOO::*)()> ()(FOO*)> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::_M_dispose() (shared_ptr_base.h:351)
==6218==    by 0x4180B7: std::_Sp_counted_base<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::_M_release() (shared_ptr_base.h:146)
==6218==    by 0x417F62: std::__shared_count<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::~__shared_count() (shared_ptr_base.h:551)
==6218==    by 0x417E99: std::__shared_ptr<std::thread::_Impl_base, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::~__shared_ptr() (shared_ptr_base.h:751)
==6218==    by 0x417EB3: std::shared_ptr<std::thread::_Impl_base>::~shared_ptr() (shared_ptr.h:93)
==6218==    by 0x418037: std::thread::thread<void (FOO::*)(), FOO*>(void (FOO::*&&)(), FOO*&&) (thread:135)
==6218==    by 0x417CCB: main (main.cpp:18)
==6218== Address 0x5b5d050 is at offset 32 from 0x5b5d030. Allocation context:
==6218==    at 0x4C2AAB7: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_drd-amd64-linux.so)
==6218==    by 0x418A5F: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_result<void, std::_Mem_fn<void (FOO::*)()> ()(FOO*)> >, std::allocator<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_result<void, std::_Mem_fn<void (FOO::*)()> ()(FOO*)> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> >::allocate(unsigned long, void const*) (new_allocator.h:92)
==6218==    by 0x418846: std::__shared_count<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::__shared_count<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_result<void, std::_Mem_fn<void (FOO::*)()> ()(FOO*)> >, std::allocator<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_result<void, std::_Mem_fn<void (FOO::*)()> ()(FOO*)> > >, std::_Bind_result<void, std::_Mem_fn<void (FOO::*)()> ()(FOO*)> >(std::_Sp_make_shared_tag, std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_result<void, std::_Mem_fn<void (FOO::*)()> ()(FOO*)> >*, std::allocator<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_result<void, std::_Mem_fn<void (FOO::*)()> ()(FOO*)> > > const&, std::_Bind_result<void, std::_Mem_fn<void (FOO::*)()> ()(FOO*)>&&) (shared_ptr_base.h:517)
==6218==    by 0x418775: std::__shared_ptr<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_result<void, std::_Mem_fn<void (FOO::*)()> ()(FOO*)> >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::__shared_ptr<std::allocator<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_result<void, std::_Mem_fn<void (FOO::*)()> ()(FOO*)> > >, std::_Bind_result<void, std::_Mem_fn<void (FOO::*)()> ()(FOO*)> >(std::_Sp_make_shared_tag, std::allocator<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_result<void, std::_Mem_fn<void (FOO::*)()> ()(FOO*)> > > const&, std::_Bind_result<void, std::_Mem_fn<void (FOO::*)()> ()(FOO*)>&&) (shared_ptr_base.h:986)
==6218==    by 0x4186C1: std::shared_ptr<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_result<void, std::_Mem_fn<void (FOO::*)()> ()(FOO*)> > >::shared_ptr<std::allocator<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_result<void, std::_Mem_fn<void (FOO::*)()> ()(FOO*)> > >, std::_Bind_result<void, std::_Mem_fn<void (FOO::*)()> ()(FOO*)> >(std::_Sp_make_shared_tag, std::allocator<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_result<void, std::_Mem_fn<void (FOO::*)()> ()(FOO*)> > > const&, std::_Bind_result<void, std::_Mem_fn<void (FOO::*)()> ()(FOO*)>&&) (shared_ptr.h:313)
==6218==    by 0x4185A3: std::shared_ptr<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_result<void, std::_Mem_fn<void (FOO::*)()> ()(FOO*)> > > std::allocate_shared<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_result<void, std::_Mem_fn<void (FOO::*)()> ()(FOO*)> >, std::allocator<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_result<void, std::_Mem_fn<void (FOO::*)()> ()(FOO*)> > >, std::_Bind_result<void, std::_Mem_fn<void (FOO::*)()> ()(FOO*)> >(std::allocator<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_result<void, std::_Mem_fn<void (FOO::*)()> ()(FOO*)> > > const&, std::_Bind_result<void, std::_Mem_fn<void (FOO::*)()> ()(FOO*)>&&) (shared_ptr.h:531)
==6218==    by 0x418360: std::shared_ptr<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_result<void, std::_Mem_fn<void (FOO::*)()> ()(FOO*)> > > std::make_shared<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_result<void, std::_Mem_fn<void (FOO::*)()> ()(FOO*)> >, std::_Bind_result<void, std::_Mem_fn<void (FOO::*)()> ()(FOO*)> >(std::_Bind_result<void, std::_Mem_fn<void (FOO::*)()> ()(FOO*)>&&) (shared_ptr.h:547)
==6218==    by 0x4181BF: std::shared_ptr<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_result<void, std::_Mem_fn<void (FOO::*)()> ()(FOO*)> > > std::thread::_M_make_routine<std::_Bind_result<void, std::_Mem_fn<void (FOO::*)()> ()(FOO*)> >(std::_Bind_result<void, std::_Mem_fn<void (FOO::*)()> ()(FOO*)>&&) (thread:194)
==6218==    by 0x418005: std::thread::thread<void (FOO::*)(), FOO*>(void (FOO::*&&)(), FOO*&&) (thread:135)
==6218==    by 0x417CCB: main (main.cpp:18)
==6218== Other segment start (thread 2)
==6218==    (thread finished, call stack no longer available)
==6218== Other segment end (thread 2)
==6218==    (thread finished, call stack no longer available)
==6218== 
==6218== Conflicting store by thread 1 at 0x05b5d050 size 8
==6218==    at 0x417EC6: std::thread::_Impl_base::~_Impl_base() (in /home/ezequiel/projects/oncordia/build/oncordia)
==6218==    by 0x418E74: std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_result<void, std::_Mem_fn<void (FOO::*)()> ()(FOO*)> >::~_Impl() (in /home/ezequiel/projects/oncordia/build/oncordia)
==6218==    by 0x419099: std::_Sp_destroy_inplace<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_result<void, std::_Mem_fn<void (FOO::*)()> ()(FOO*)> > >::operator()(std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_result<void, std::_Mem_fn<void (FOO::*)()> ()(FOO*)> >*) const (in /home/ezequiel/projects/oncordia/build/oncordia)
==6218==    by 0x418EDC: std::_Sp_counted_deleter<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_result<void, std::_Mem_fn<void (FOO::*)()> ()(FOO*)> >*, std::_Sp_destroy_inplace<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_result<void, std::_Mem_fn<void (FOO::*)()> ()(FOO*)> > >, std::allocator<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_result<void, std::_Mem_fn<void (FOO::*)()> ()(FOO*)> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::_M_dispose() (shared_ptr_base.h:351)
==6218==    by 0x4180B7: std::_Sp_counted_base<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::_M_release() (shared_ptr_base.h:146)
==6218==    by 0x417F62: std::__shared_count<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::~__shared_count() (shared_ptr_base.h:551)
==6218==    by 0x417E99: std::__shared_ptr<std::thread::_Impl_base, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::~__shared_ptr() (shared_ptr_base.h:751)
==6218==    by 0x417EB3: std::shared_ptr<std::thread::_Impl_base>::~shared_ptr() (shared_ptr.h:93)
==6218==    by 0x418037: std::thread::thread<void (FOO::*)(), FOO*>(void (FOO::*&&)(), FOO*&&) (thread:135)
==6218==    by 0x417CCB: main (main.cpp:18)
==6218== Address 0x5b5d050 is at offset 32 from 0x5b5d030. Allocation context:
==6218==    at 0x4C2AAB7: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_drd-amd64-linux.so)
==6218==    by 0x418A5F: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_result<void, std::_Mem_fn<void (FOO::*)()> ()(FOO*)> >, std::allocator<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_result<void, std::_Mem_fn<void (FOO::*)()> ()(FOO*)> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> >::allocate(unsigned long, void const*) (new_allocator.h:92)
==6218==    by 0x418846: std::__shared_count<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::__shared_count<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_result<void, std::_Mem_fn<void (FOO::*)()> ()(FOO*)> >, std::allocator<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_result<void, std::_Mem_fn<void (FOO::*)()> ()(FOO*)> > >, std::_Bind_result<void, std::_Mem_fn<void (FOO::*)()> ()(FOO*)> >(std::_Sp_make_shared_tag, std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_result<void, std::_Mem_fn<void (FOO::*)()> ()(FOO*)> >*, std::allocator<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_result<void, std::_Mem_fn<void (FOO::*)()> ()(FOO*)> > > const&, std::_Bind_result<void, std::_Mem_fn<void (FOO::*)()> ()(FOO*)>&&) (shared_ptr_base.h:517)
==6218==    by 0x418775: std::__shared_ptr<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_result<void, std::_Mem_fn<void (FOO::*)()> ()(FOO*)> >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::__shared_ptr<std::allocator<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_result<void, std::_Mem_fn<void (FOO::*)()> ()(FOO*)> > >, std::_Bind_result<void, std::_Mem_fn<void (FOO::*)()> ()(FOO*)> >(std::_Sp_make_shared_tag, std::allocator<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_result<void, std::_Mem_fn<void (FOO::*)()> ()(FOO*)> > > const&, std::_Bind_result<void, std::_Mem_fn<void (FOO::*)()> ()(FOO*)>&&) (shared_ptr_base.h:986)
==6218==    by 0x4186C1: std::shared_ptr<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_result<void, std::_Mem_fn<void (FOO::*)()> ()(FOO*)> > >::shared_ptr<std::allocator<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_result<void, std::_Mem_fn<void (FOO::*)()> ()(FOO*)> > >, std::_Bind_result<void, std::_Mem_fn<void (FOO::*)()> ()(FOO*)> >(std::_Sp_make_shared_tag, std::allocator<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_result<void, std::_Mem_fn<void (FOO::*)()> ()(FOO*)> > > const&, std::_Bind_result<void, std::_Mem_fn<void (FOO::*)()> ()(FOO*)>&&) (shared_ptr.h:313)
==6218==    by 0x4185A3: std::shared_ptr<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_result<void, std::_Mem_fn<void (FOO::*)()> ()(FOO*)> > > std::allocate_shared<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_result<void, std::_Mem_fn<void (FOO::*)()> ()(FOO*)> >, std::allocator<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_result<void, std::_Mem_fn<void (FOO::*)()> ()(FOO*)> > >, std::_Bind_result<void, std::_Mem_fn<void (FOO::*)()> ()(FOO*)> >(std::allocator<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_result<void, std::_Mem_fn<void (FOO::*)()> ()(FOO*)> > > const&, std::_Bind_result<void, std::_Mem_fn<void (FOO::*)()> ()(FOO*)>&&) (shared_ptr.h:531)
==6218==    by 0x418360: std::shared_ptr<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_result<void, std::_Mem_fn<void (FOO::*)()> ()(FOO*)> > > std::make_shared<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_result<void, std::_Mem_fn<void (FOO::*)()> ()(FOO*)> >, std::_Bind_result<void, std::_Mem_fn<void (FOO::*)()> ()(FOO*)> >(std::_Bind_result<void, std::_Mem_fn<void (FOO::*)()> ()(FOO*)>&&) (shared_ptr.h:547)
==6218==    by 0x4181BF: std::shared_ptr<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_result<void, std::_Mem_fn<void (FOO::*)()> ()(FOO*)> > > std::thread::_M_make_routine<std::_Bind_result<void, std::_Mem_fn<void (FOO::*)()> ()(FOO*)> >(std::_Bind_result<void, std::_Mem_fn<void (FOO::*)()> ()(FOO*)>&&) (thread:194)
==6218==    by 0x418005: std::thread::thread<void (FOO::*)(), FOO*>(void (FOO::*&&)(), FOO*&&) (thread:135)
==6218==    by 0x417CCB: main (main.cpp:18)
==6218== Other segment start (thread 2)
==6218==    (thread finished, call stack no longer available)
==6218== Other segment end (thread 2)
==6218==    (thread finished, call stack no longer available)
==6218== 
==6218== Conflicting load by thread 1 at 0x05b5d060 size 8
==6218==    at 0x417F4C: std::__shared_count<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::~__shared_count() (shared_ptr_base.h:550)
==6218==    by 0x417E99: std::__shared_ptr<std::thread::_Impl_base, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::~__shared_ptr() (shared_ptr_base.h:751)
==6218==    by 0x417EB3: std::shared_ptr<std::thread::_Impl_base>::~shared_ptr() (shared_ptr.h:93)
==6218==    by 0x417EDC: std::thread::_Impl_base::~_Impl_base() (in /home/ezequiel/projects/oncordia/build/oncordia)
==6218==    by 0x418E74: std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_result<void, std::_Mem_fn<void (FOO::*)()> ()(FOO*)> >::~_Impl() (in /home/ezequiel/projects/oncordia/build/oncordia)
==6218==    by 0x419099: std::_Sp_destroy_inplace<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_result<void, std::_Mem_fn<void (FOO::*)()> ()(FOO*)> > >::operator()(std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_result<void, std::_Mem_fn<void (FOO::*)()> ()(FOO*)> >*) const (in /home/ezequiel/projects/oncordia/build/oncordia)
==6218==    by 0x418EDC: std::_Sp_counted_deleter<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_result<void, std::_Mem_fn<void (FOO::*)()> ()(FOO*)> >*, std::_Sp_destroy_inplace<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_result<void, std::_Mem_fn<void (FOO::*)()> ()(FOO*)> > >, std::allocator<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_result<void, std::_Mem_fn<void (FOO::*)()> ()(FOO*)> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::_M_dispose() (shared_ptr_base.h:351)
==6218==    by 0x4180B7: std::_Sp_counted_base<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::_M_release() (shared_ptr_base.h:146)
==6218==    by 0x417F62: std::__shared_count<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::~__shared_count() (shared_ptr_base.h:551)
==6218==    by 0x417E99: std::__shared_ptr<std::thread::_Impl_base, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::~__shared_ptr() (shared_ptr_base.h:751)
==6218==    by 0x417EB3: std::shared_ptr<std::thread::_Impl_base>::~shared_ptr() (shared_ptr.h:93)
==6218==    by 0x418037: std::thread::thread<void (FOO::*)(), FOO*>(void (FOO::*&&)(), FOO*&&) (thread:135)
==6218== Address 0x5b5d060 is at offset 48 from 0x5b5d030. Allocation context:
==6218==    at 0x4C2AAB7: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_drd-amd64-linux.so)
==6218==    by 0x418A5F: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_result<void, std::_Mem_fn<void (FOO::*)()> ()(FOO*)> >, std::allocator<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_result<void, std::_Mem_fn<void (FOO::*)()> ()(FOO*)> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> >::allocate(unsigned long, void const*) (new_allocator.h:92)
==6218==    by 0x418846: std::__shared_count<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::__shared_count<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_result<void, std::_Mem_fn<void (FOO::*)()> ()(FOO*)> >, std::allocator<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_result<void, std::_Mem_fn<void (FOO::*)()> ()(FOO*)> > >, std::_Bind_result<void, std::_Mem_fn<void (FOO::*)()> ()(FOO*)> >(std::_Sp_make_shared_tag, std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_result<void, std::_Mem_fn<void (FOO::*)()> ()(FOO*)> >*, std::allocator<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_result<void, std::_Mem_fn<void (FOO::*)()> ()(FOO*)> > > const&, std::_Bind_result<void, std::_Mem_fn<void (FOO::*)()> ()(FOO*)>&&) (shared_ptr_base.h:517)
==6218==    by 0x418775: std::__shared_ptr<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_result<void, std::_Mem_fn<void (FOO::*)()> ()(FOO*)> >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::__shared_ptr<std::allocator<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_result<void, std::_Mem_fn<void (FOO::*)()> ()(FOO*)> > >, std::_Bind_result<void, std::_Mem_fn<void (FOO::*)()> ()(FOO*)> >(std::_Sp_make_shared_tag, std::allocator<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_result<void, std::_Mem_fn<void (FOO::*)()> ()(FOO*)> > > const&, std::_Bind_result<void, std::_Mem_fn<void (FOO::*)()> ()(FOO*)>&&) (shared_ptr_base.h:986)
==6218==    by 0x4186C1: std::shared_ptr<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_result<void, std::_Mem_fn<void (FOO::*)()> ()(FOO*)> > >::shared_ptr<std::allocator<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_result<void, std::_Mem_fn<void (FOO::*)()> ()(FOO*)> > >, std::_Bind_result<void, std::_Mem_fn<void (FOO::*)()> ()(FOO*)> >(std::_Sp_make_shared_tag, std::allocator<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_result<void, std::_Mem_fn<void (FOO::*)()> ()(FOO*)> > > const&, std::_Bind_result<void, std::_Mem_fn<void (FOO::*)()> ()(FOO*)>&&) (shared_ptr.h:313)
==6218==    by 0x4185A3: std::shared_ptr<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_result<void, std::_Mem_fn<void (FOO::*)()> ()(FOO*)> > > std::allocate_shared<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_result<void, std::_Mem_fn<void (FOO::*)()> ()(FOO*)> >, std::allocator<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_result<void, std::_Mem_fn<void (FOO::*)()> ()(FOO*)> > >, std::_Bind_result<void, std::_Mem_fn<void (FOO::*)()> ()(FOO*)> >(std::allocator<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_result<void, std::_Mem_fn<void (FOO::*)()> ()(FOO*)> > > const&, std::_Bind_result<void, std::_Mem_fn<void (FOO::*)()> ()(FOO*)>&&) (shared_ptr.h:531)
==6218==    by 0x418360: std::shared_ptr<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_result<void, std::_Mem_fn<void (FOO::*)()> ()(FOO*)> > > std::make_shared<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_result<void, std::_Mem_fn<void (FOO::*)()> ()(FOO*)> >, std::_Bind_result<void, std::_Mem_fn<void (FOO::*)()> ()(FOO*)> >(std::_Bind_result<void, std::_Mem_fn<void (FOO::*)()> ()(FOO*)>&&) (shared_ptr.h:547)
==6218==    by 0x4181BF: std::shared_ptr<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_result<void, std::_Mem_fn<void (FOO::*)()> ()(FOO*)> > > std::thread::_M_make_routine<std::_Bind_result<void, std::_Mem_fn<void (FOO::*)()> ()(FOO*)> >(std::_Bind_result<void, std::_Mem_fn<void (FOO::*)()> ()(FOO*)>&&) (thread:194)
==6218==    by 0x418005: std::thread::thread<void (FOO::*)(), FOO*>(void (FOO::*&&)(), FOO*&&) (thread:135)
==6218==    by 0x417CCB: main (main.cpp:18)
==6218== Other segment start (thread 2)
==6218==    (thread finished, call stack no longer available)
==6218== Other segment end (thread 2)
==6218==    (thread finished, call stack no longer available)
==6218== 
==6218== 
==6218== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
```

thanks!!

Comment: @Tudor, you have to pass the instance of FOO as a pointer which is why there is `&foo`. That said, I aren't actually sure what the question is, does that code work as expected?

Comment: My cuestion is why i get these errors?... The code work as expected

Comment: the code looks fine. Do you get the errors if you don't use stdout?

Comment: Yes get error with or without cout

Comment: Also return an int from your main() function for completeness.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Read the fabulous manual: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/debug.html#debug.races

The code is OK, valgrind doesn't understand the atomic operations we use inside `std::shared_ptr` and incorrectly reports them as races.

Answer (score 0):

cout is a resource and should be mutex-ed (race condition if >1 thread of do_something() or other uses of cout)